# Logout Issue in MonoTouch.SlideoutNavigation in iOS(Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, navigation

I am newbie in iOS. I am creating SlideoutNavigation Menu using below Component of Xamarin. The Github link is below.

**Link :** https://github.com/thedillonb/MonoTouch.SlideoutNavigation

In this Component the whole thing is working fine. But I have a little Issue.

Initially my `LoginViewController` is looking like this.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

There is no Menu Button in the Left side.

Now When I login the New Open Screen with the Menu is look like this

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Now When open the SlideOut menu and select the `Logout` Option I want to start my `LoginViewController` it also working fine using below code.

**Code :**

```
var loginViewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewController") as ViewController;
BizApplication.clearCredential();
StyledStringElement logout = new StyledStringElement("Logout", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(loginViewController, true)){ TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
logout.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");
```

But Now I am getting below Screen which is not want. I want to remove that Left Menu icon in the Navigation.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Any Help be Appreciated.

Update :

push code for new Controller open :

```
if (BizApplication.getCredential() != null)
                    {
                        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
                        Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();

                        var webController2 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SearchViewController") as SearchViewController;
                        NavigationController.PushViewController(webController2, true);

                        Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(webController2, Menu);
                        Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new DummyControllerLeft(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };

                        window.RootViewController = Menu;
                        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

                        loadingOverlay.Hide();
                    }
```

**My Flow :**

I have use only one StoryBoard for my Project. So all the ViewController are in the same StoryBoard.

**Deployment Info :**

[image]

**AppDelegate.cs** I am not changing anything in this file.

**SplashViewController.cs**

```
public partial class SplashViewController : UIViewController
    {
        UIWindow window;

        UIViewController container;

        UIStoryboard storyboard;

        public SlideoutNavigationController Menu { get; private set; }

        public SplashViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            if (Reachability.IsHostReachable("http://google.com"))
            {
                if (BizApplication.CheckCredential())
                {
                    window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

                    Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();

                    storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
                    var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SearchViewController") as SearchViewController;

                    NavigationController.PushViewController(webController, true);

                    Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(webController, Menu);
                    Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new DummyControllerLeft(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };

                    window.RootViewController = Menu;
                    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

                }
                else {
                    storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
                    var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewController") as ViewController;
                    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(webController, true);

                }
            }
        }

        public void pushMenu()
        {

            UINavigationController navMin = (UINavigationController)window.RootViewController;
            Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();
            storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
            var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SearchViewController") as SearchViewController;

            Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(webController, Menu);
            Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new DummyControllerLeft(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };
            navMin.PushViewController(Menu, true);

        }


}
```

**ViewController.cs (is My Login view Controller)**

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        LoadingOverlay loadingOverlay;

        UIWindow window;

        public SlideoutNavigationController Menu { get; private set; }

        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            this.Title = "Log In";
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;


        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
            this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true, false);
            this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f);
            this.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;

            txtfield_Username.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
            txtfield_Username.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 1.0f).CGColor;

            txtfield_password.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
            txtfield_password.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 1.0f).CGColor;

            lbl_forgetPassword.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f);

            btn_register.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var webController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("RegisterController") as RegisterController;
                NavigationController.PushViewController(webController, true);
            };

            btn_login.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
                View.Add(loadingOverlay);

                Token token = await Authonicator.Authonicate(txtfield_Username.Text, txtfield_password.Text);
                if (token != null)
                {
                    AppCredentials credentials = new AppCredentials();
                    credentials.Token = token;
                    credentials.UserName = txtfield_Username.Text;

                    var userItem = await UserClient.GetUserInfo(token.Access_token);
                    if (userItem != null)
                    {
                        credentials.Id = userItem.Id;
                        credentials.Name = userItem.Name.FirstName + " " + userItem.Name.LastName;
                        credentials.Names.FirstName = userItem.Name.FirstName;
                        credentials.Names.MiddleName = userItem.Name.MiddleName;
                        credentials.Names.LastName = userItem.Name.LastName;
                        credentials.Role = userItem.Role;
                        credentials.Contact = userItem.Mobile;
                    }
                    BizApplication.setCredential(credentials);

                    if (BizApplication.getCredential() != null)
                    {
                        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
                        Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();

                        var webController2 = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SearchViewController") as SearchViewController;

                        Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController(webController2, Menu);
                        Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController(new DummyControllerLeft(), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };

                        window.RootViewController = Menu;
                        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

                        loadingOverlay.Hide();
                    }
                }
                else {

                    UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create("Authorization", "Enter Valid Username and Password", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, Action => { }));
                    PresentViewController(alert, true, null);

                    loadingOverlay.Hide();
                }
            };
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }
    }
```

**DummyControllerLeft.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CoreAnimation;
using Foundation;
using Gargi.Business;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;
using UIKit;

namespace Gargi.iOS
{
    public class DummyControllerLeft : DialogViewController
    {
        public static UIImageView profileImage;

        public DummyControllerLeft(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {

        }

        public DummyControllerLeft()
           : base(UITableViewStyle.Plain, new RootElement(""))
        {

            var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

            var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SearchViewController") as SearchViewController;
            StyledStringElement search = new StyledStringElement("Search", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(webController, true)) { TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            search.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");

            var appointController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AppointmentListController") as AppointmentListController;
            StyledStringElement appointment = new StyledStringElement("Appointment", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(appointController, true)) { TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            appointment.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");

            var caseHistoryController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("CaseHistoryController") as CaseHistoryController;
            StyledStringElement casehistory = new StyledStringElement("CaseHistory", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(caseHistoryController, true)){ TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            casehistory.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");

            var accountController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AccountViewController") as AccountViewController;
            StyledStringElement account = new StyledStringElement("Account", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(accountController, true)){ TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            account.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");

            var securityController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecurityViewController") as SecurityViewController;
            StyledStringElement security = new StyledStringElement("Security", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(securityController, true)){ TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            security.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");

            var workProfileController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("WorkProfileViewController") as WorkProfileViewController;
            StyledStringElement workProfile = new StyledStringElement("WorkProfile", () => NavigationController.PushViewController(workProfileController, true)){ TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            workProfile.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");

            BizApplication.clearCredential();

            StyledStringElement logout = new StyledStringElement("Logout",() => CallthisMethod()){ TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            logout.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");

            Root.Add(new Section()
            {
                search,
                appointment,
                casehistory,
                account,
                security,
                workProfile,
                logout
            } );

            TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
            TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f);
        }

        void CallthisMethod()
        {
            var vwControllers = NavigationController.ViewControllers;

            foreach (UIViewController signiinVC in vwControllers)
            {
                if (signiinVC.GetType() == typeof(ViewController))
                {
                    this.NavigationController.PopToViewController(signiinVC,true);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            TableView.Frame = new RectangleF((float)TableView.Frame.Left, (float)(TableView.Frame.Top + 30), (float)TableView.Frame.Width, (float)(TableView.Frame.Height - 30));
            UIView headerView = new UIView();
            headerView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, TableView.Frame.Width, 140);
            //headerView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#004F80", 1.0f);

            profileImage = new UIImageView();
            profileImage.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, 70, 70);
            profileImage.Layer.CornerRadius = 35;
            profileImage.ClipsToBounds = true;
            profileImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("gargi_logo.png");

            UILabel userName = new UILabel();
            userName.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 90, TableView.Frame.Width - 20, 20);
            userName.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 14f);
            userName.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            headerView.AddSubview(userName);

            UILabel userRole = new UILabel();
            userRole.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 110, TableView.Frame.Width - 20, 20);
            userRole.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica-Bold", 14f);
            userRole.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            headerView.AddSubview(userRole);

            headerView.AddSubview(profileImage);
            TableView.TableHeaderView = headerView;

            if (BizApplication.getCredential().Name != null)
            {
                userName.Text = BizApplication.getCredential().Name;
            }

            if (BizApplication.getCredential().Role != null)
            {
                userRole.Text = BizApplication.getCredential().Role;
            }

            var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradient.Frame = headerView.Frame;
            gradient.Colors = new CoreGraphics.CGColor[] { UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f).CGColor,UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#004f80",1.0f).CGColor};
            headerView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradient, 0);

            var task = GetUserImage();

        }

        private async Task GetUserImage()
        {
            var userHeader = await UserClient.GetHeaderData();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userHeader.Image))
            {
                string trimbase = userHeader.Image.Trim('"');
                try
                {
                    var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(trimbase);
                    var imageData = NSData.FromArray(imageBytes);
                    profileImage.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                    profileImage.Layer.CornerRadius = 35;
                    profileImage.ClipsToBounds = true;
                    profileImage.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## Update latest :

If I do this in the **DummyLeftControllers.cs** then nothing is happen :

```
StyledStringElement logout = new StyledStringElement("Logout",() => CallthisMethod(storyboard)){ TextColor = UIColor.White, BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            logout.Image = new UIImage("filter_icon.png");


void CallthisMethod(UIStoryboard storyboard)
        {
            var vwControllers = NavigationController.ViewControllers;

            foreach (UIViewController signiinVC in vwControllers)
            {
                if (signiinVC.GetType() == typeof(ViewController))
                {
                    this.NavigationController.PopToViewController(signiinVC, true);
                }
            }

            BizApplication.clearCredential();

            NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);

    }
```

Comment: How you are pushing new screen when login is completed? Can you please share code for that?

Comment: @NinjaHattori see my update code.

Comment: @NinjaHattori if you require other code then just tell me I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing SignInView controller on stack on Logout--which is incorrect. Write your code in a way that It use previously pushed view from stack..

In Splashviewconrtroller change following in viewdidload method:

```
 base.ViewDidUnload ();

            storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
            var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("ViewController") as ViewController;
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController (webController, false);


            if (Reachability.IsHostReachable ("http://google.com")) {
                if (BizApplication.CheckCredential ()) {
                    //window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

                    Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController ();

                    storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
                    var webController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("SearchViewController") as SearchViewController;

                    NavigationController.PushViewController (webController, false);

                    Menu.MainViewController = new MainNavigationController (webController, Menu);
                    Menu.MenuViewController = new MenuNavigationController (new DummyControllerLeft (), Menu) { NavigationBarHidden = true };
                    this.NavigationController.PushViewController (Menu);
                    //window.RootViewController = Menu;
                    //window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

                }  
            }
```

On Logout..Call following:

```
void onLogOut (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    //Write your code to clear
             var vwControllers = this.NavigationController.ViewControllers;
        foreach(UIViewController signinVC in vwControllers) {
            if (signinVC.GetType () == typeof (ViewController)) {
                this.NavigationController.PopToViewController (ViewController);
            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: Wait i try out the solution and came back to you soon.

Comment: I have liitle Problem Because I use `SpalshViewController` in the Storyboard.

Comment: Can you please explain what problem you have?

Comment: see my update question. I have call as you say see my `DummyControllerLeft.cs` file.

Comment: You have not specified what problem you are facing now?

Comment: In splash view controller, you are still creating new window window.RootViewController = Menu;
                    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();   -- You should not create this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132876/discussion-between-ironman-and-ninja-hattori).

Answer (score 0):

i think u should present your view controller modally there is no need to push them in stack as u don't need back button.

instead of

```
navigationcontroller.pushviewcontroller()
```

use

```
presentviewcontroller()
```

you can use `dismissviewcntroller()` when logout and this will not change your navigationbar in login screen